# NaN output when multiplying row and column of dataframe in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nan, multiplication

I have two data frames the first one looks like this:
[image: first data frame]

and the second one like so:
[image: second data frame]

I am trying to multiply the values in number of donors column of the second data frame(96 values) with the values in the first row of the first data frame and columns 0-95 (also 96 values).

Below is the code I have for multiplying the two right now, but as you can see the values are all NaN:

[image: code]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Please, avoid using images as code. Check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Your second dataframe has dtype `object`, you must convert it to `float`

```
df_sls.iloc[0,3:-1].astype(float)
```

Comment: I had actually tried that earlier and it didn't work. I updated the code in the image above to represent that